# Wake up Windows 10 Automatically

Tags: windows-10, windows-task-scheduler, wake-up

I've spent the last few hours reading and trying different methods to wake up my Windows 10 laptop from Hibernation or Sleep, so far with no luck.

Initially the idea was to use Task Scheduler but I cannot for the life of me get this working. Has anyone had similar issues or found a good 3rd party application that can wake up Windows 10?

Comment: Follow this article completely:  https://www.howtogeek.com/119028/how-to-make-your-pc-wake-from-sleep-automatically/  .  Make sure you use Suspend and not Hibernate.  Make sure you use regular suspend, not Hybrid Sleep or Modern Sleep.

Comment: For a quick TL;DR about hibernation vs suspend for anyone wondering - it essentially saves the state of the OS and shuts it down - and when starting back up, just restores this state (After you hibernate, you can remove power for as long as you like and when you turn it back on, it'll be no different). Suspend keeps it running but in a lower power mode.

Comment: Thanks @John and QuickishFM, I don't have the option to enable sleep timers or enable or disable hybrid sleep. Still not able to get it working.

Comment: I will keep looking. I use procedures like this a while back and now longer bother. With SSD drives, time before suspending is longer and fewer intervals so I just wake the machines up manually or by opening the lid